# Filling array gives unexpected values

Tags: c, arrays, memory

I have a serious problem when filling an array. My functions looks like this:

```
int s_in[]; /* Array filled with a lot of integer values */
for(frame=0; frame<maxFrames; frame++){
  left = 240*(frame-1) + 1;
  right = 240*(frame +1);
  int x[right-left+1]; /* is always 480 long */

  for(i=left-1;i<right;i++){
    x[i] = s_in[i];
  }
```

When I now try to print out the values stored in x[] for each run, I often either get an empty x[] or some random numbers that do not appear in the s_in[].
Can that problem be solved with some kind of memory management?

Comment: Sorry, it's in C.

Comment: Can you show us what you're putting into `s_in`?

Comment: Where are you printing `x`. Is it inside the `frame` for loop, or outside?

Comment: When indexing `x` you must always use a value between 0 and 479. When `frame` > 0 then `i` will have values that are >480.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems in the line:

```
x[i] = s_in[i];
```

On the very first iteration, when the aboce line is executed, the values of the variables are:

```
frame:    0
left:  -239
i:     -240
```

**The code attempts to read from outside of bounds of `s_in[]` and to write writes outside of bounds of `x[]`.**

This is [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

It's difficult to provide a fix to the code without knowing how the information is laid out in `s_in[]`. Assuming a frame is 240 bytes and on each iteration you want to copy the values for two consecutive frames from `s_in[]` into `x[]`, the code should look something along these lines:

```
int s_in[]; /* Array filled with a lot of integer values */
for (frame = 1; frame < maxFrames; frame ++) {
  left  = 240 * (frame - 1);        /* the first value of the previous frame */
  right = 240 * (frame + 1);        /* the first value of the next frame */
  int x[480];                       /* is always 480 long */

  for (i = 0; i < 480; i ++) {
    x[i] = s_in[left + i];
  }
}
```

There is no point in computing `right-left+1` on each iteration since you already know it must be `480`. As you can see from the code above, the value of `right` is not even needed.

The outer loop should start with `frame = 0` but for frame `#0` the offending line attempts to read from outside `s_in[]`; this is why it starts with frame `#1`.

I suppose you do more processing inside the inner loop. Otherwise you can replace it with a call to [`memcpy(&x, &s_in[left], 480);`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy). It does the same as the current status of the `for` loop but it runs much faster.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I changed the code and applied your suggestions. Now I am getting a segmentation fault at frame 253, and I just don't know why. I only get the error when I try to print out the values of the x[]. I am  sure, that the s_in[] is filled within this frame, but how can it be, that it only gives me the segmentation fault when I try to read and print the x[] array?

Answer (score 1):

You algorithm get's out of the bounds of the x array. When you iterate over the frames you get values longer than the max size of the x array and then you try to access x positions that doesn't have been reserved on memory, hence the weird numbers. Always remember that C doesn't check if an array is out of bounds